# get No Class Def Found Error:scala/Product$class when packaging fat jar

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, packaging, fatjar

Created a simple helloworld scala program on intellij and tried to add assembly plug in. But every time I run "assembly" on sbt console I get no class def. found error.

Build.sbt:

```
name := "testsbt"

version := "1.2.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" %"test"

autoScalaLibrary := true
```

Assembly.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.7")
```

Error message:

```
[IJ]sbt:testsbt> assembly
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
```

scala version and sbt version are matched.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does your application code look like? Can you post that too? (BTW, use `"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % Test` - you're explicitly using the _wrong_, _Scala_ 2.11, version of _ScalaTest_.)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _"scala version and sbt version are matched"_? The version of _SBT_ is governed by the contents of `./project/build.properties`, and not necessarily by the version you have installed. The two do _not_ need to be matched, typically.